# Difference between Selenium RC and Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium RC:

The selenium commands are passed to Proxy server. Proxy server converts the selenium command in to Javascript and it will inject on the browser.

Selenium Webdriver:

The selenium commands are interpreated by selenium ApI and the selenium API will pass the command to Browser Native API and it will be executed..

Correct me if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver is the successor of Selenium Remote Control (RC) which has been officially deprecated. @ http://docs.seleniumhq.org/